# Does this parsing data way really works?

Tags: json, parsing, adaptive-cards

Am reading this "issue" from the guys from adaptive cards, and am trying to use their parsing way in my own project with no results. Here´s the entire thing https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/2448 the parsing section is below. Does this implementation really work?

JSON.parse Example

This is an Azure DevOps response where the message property is a JSON-serialized string. In order to access values within the string, we need to use the JSON.parse function in our template.

```
Data
    {
        "id": "1291525457129548",
        "status": 4,
        "author": "Matt Hidinger",
        "message": "{\"type\":\"Deployment\",\"buildId\":\"9542982\",\"releaseId\":\"129\",\"buildNumber\":\"20180504.3\",\"releaseName\":\"Release-104\",\"repoProvider\":\"GitHub\"}",
        "start_time": "2018-05-04T18:05:33.3087147Z",
        "end_time": "2018-05-04T18:05:33.3087147Z"
    }
    Usage
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "{JSON.parse(message).releaseName}"
    }
    Resulting In
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Release-104"
    }
```

Comment: Which SDK are you trying to use this in? It's supposed to work using the adaptivecards-templating library for JS on npm. The other SDKs are not supported yet in the preview. If you're trying js can you include the version and code usage?

Comment: The question was specifically referred to about this example. I completely ignored the existence of this npm packageadaptivecards-templating. Will try to use it in my own project, thanks for mentioning it.